# How to load resource from another package in xml?

Tags: android, xml, layout, resources, drawable

I know that exists ability to install resource xml file from another package in code like this:

```
String resourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(layoutResID);
String resourceTypeName = getResources().getResourceTypeName(layoutResID);
Resources skinResources = getResourcesForPackage("com.my.skin");
int skinResourceId = skinResources.getIdentifier(resourceName, resourceTypeName, "com.my.skin");
mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
mLayoutInflater.inflate(skinResources.getXml(skinResourceId), null);
super.setContentView(mLayoutInflater.inflate(skinResources.getXml(skinResourceId), null));
```

But i would like to know how to make the same but in xml and for drawable resources:

For example: I have two applications:

- application **main** with package "*com.my.main*"
- and application **skin** with package "*com.my.skin*"

In android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground) explained:

> May be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name".

I have tried to specify something like this:

`android:background="@com.my.skin:drawable:background_image"`

or this:

`android:background="?com.my.skin:drawable:background_image"`

but it not work, my resource file not compiled.

**Who know how to load resource using explicit specification.**

Answer (score 1):

Make your project a library project and you can refer it in another android project.

Library Projects

These projects contain shareable Android **source code** and **resources that you can reference in Android projects**. This is useful when you have common code that you want to reuse. Library projects cannot be installed onto a device, however, they are pulled into the .apk file at build time.

For more information have a look at the link under the topic **Library Projects.**

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Your library project will have a check box ticked as shown in the project.

[image]

You can add library project to your android project. Right click on your project. Goto properties. Choose Android on the left panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you forgot to add + after @. And there is a mistype in drawable format last : should be raplaced to /

This should be the correct option:

```
android:background="@+com.my.skin:drawable/background_image"
```